# Использование static для реализации паттерна singleton в c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, static, singleton

Здраствуйте. Я тут начал изучать паттерны и добрался до singleton'ов. Начал рассматривать примеры (все примерно такие:

```
struct singleton
{
    static singleton& get_instance()
    {
        static singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    singleton(singleton const&) = delete;
    singleton(singleton&&) = delete;
    int a = 0;

private:
    singleton() { }

};

int main()
{
    singleton& s = singleton::get_instance();
    s.a = 42;
}
```

), и у меня назрел вопрос: зачем вообще работать с экземплярами класса, когда можно сделать через статику?
Например,

```
struct Single{
    Single(Single &&) = delete;
    Single(const Single&) = delete;
    static int a;
};
int Single::a = 0;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Single::a = 42;
}
```

Comment: ну к примеру у тебя есть класс "настройки приложения" он читается из файла при запуске, и ты не хочешь 10 раз читать его при создании экземпляра в разных частях приложения, а хочешь работать с одной его копией. если ты будешь работать с переменной то ты можешь ее поменять, но положим ты хочешь проверять значения которые ты переменной присваиваешь, в случае с классом ты можешь эту логику реализовать в случае обычной переменной ты можешь ее поменять напрямую без проверок, ладно если ты сам пишешь код ты сам себе виноват, а если ты делаешь код который используют другие, то ты можешь ограничить

Comment: возможность выстрелить себе в ногу менее опытным разработчикам, которые хотят использовать твой код синглтоны как раз позволяют абстрагировать код, и сделать работу с одним его экземпляром безопасным. например ты хочешь чтобы настройки читались и писались в потоке без необходимости контроля тобой синхронизации всего этого, ты добавляешь код для синхронизации потоков, и класс "настройки" становится потокобезопасным, и у конечного потребителя твоего класса уже об этом голова не болит. и напрямую поменять переменную и выстрелить себе в ногу ты ему не даешь.

Comment: в c++ ты можешь использовать в структуре методы, а саму переменную засунуть в приват

Comment: хотя насчет потоков ты прав, что то не подумал об этом.

Comment: в с++ разница между структурой и классом скоро вообще (наверное) будет нивелирована до минимума.

Comment: собственно наверное кроме разницы в дефолтной области видимости членов класса и структуры различий и не осталось. ну может еще выравнивание в памяти для структуры можно задать, и то это от компилятора зависит. а вот, структура не может быть шаблоном, а класс может. вот и все различия.

Comment: Это совершенно разные понятия

Comment: слушай, я тут задумался, а какие проблемы с потоками могут возникнуть?
ну всм таки, которые не могла бы решить статика?

Comment: ну если ты переменную опишешь как атомик бул, то наверное маловероятно, что один поток другому может что-то испортить, то и тут можно наступить на грабли. но переменные не все булевые, и иногда нужно поменять несколько переменных, ну к примеру строку, или размер массива и сам массив, и тогда ты в один такт не уложишься никак, и при наличии более одного потока работающего с одним набором данных эти операции нужно разграничивать явно.

Comment: а можно закостылить и просто ввести статическую белевкую переменную in_progress с одноименным значением и сделать гетеры/сетеры и в них уже производить проверки

Comment: ну или использовать мьютексы\симафоры)

Comment: @Yakov *"выравнивание в памяти для структуры можно задать, и то это от компилятора зависит. а вот, структура не может быть шаблоном"* Структура может быть шаблоном, а классу можно задать выравнивание. Кроме дефолтной видимости полей и родителей разницы нет вообще. Да и строго говоря, в С++ нет структур, а слово `struct` создает класс...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и у меня назрел вопрос: зачем вообще работать с экземплярами класса, когда можно сделать через статику?

Экземпляр можно куда-то передать, вернуть из функции, дать его адрес другой библиотеке и т.д., т.е. у нас именно объект-одиночка, а не набор несвязных друг с другом переменных, собранных в пространстве класса.

Создание экземпляра можно контролировать, просто static-поля - нет.
Для примера последнего посмотрим на код:

```
//one.h
struct MySingleton
{
    //...
    static int a;
};

//one.cpp
int MySingleton::a = 10;

//two.cpp
//...
int b = MySingleton::a; //static initialization order fiasco
```

В данном случае неизвестно, какая переменная будет инициализирована ранее - `b` в `two.cpp` или `MySingleton::a` в `one.cpp`, а значит у нас большие проблемы.

Также необходимо как-то реализовать правильную инициализацию всего этого добра, собранного в скоупе класса. Ваше предложение, -

> ну можно где-нибудь вызвать статический метод init() / destroy()

это двухэтапные инициализация и уничтожение, для избежания которых придумали конструкторы, деструкторы и т.д... Можно же вообще обойтись без класса, не так ли? Почему же тогда вас не смущает вообще наличие классов в языке?

А теперь посмотрим на часть кода, приведенного вами:

```
static singleton& get_instance()
{
    static singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Это т.н. синглтон Майерса. Чтобы достучаться до объекта, придется вызвать `get_instance`, что приведет к созданию объекта при первом вызове. Особенность данной реализации еще в том, что начиная с C++11, инициализация этого синглтона является потокобезопасной, что гарантируется непосредственно языком и не нужно городить костыли, в которых могут быть еще и ошибки как, например, печально известный [double checked locking](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

P.S. И не забывайте про операторы присваивания и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Все можно, но есть ряд вопросов.

- а если Вашему классу нужно сложное создание/удаление (пример - подключение к базе данных)?

  > Да, можно сделать функцию Init, но тут сразу куча проблем - где именно вызывать, а если нужна ленивая загрузка, а если многопоточность.
- а если Вашему классу нужна сложная внутренняя логика (ну не хочется, что бы два потока одновременно в базу много писали/читали)?

  > давайте попроще. Есть два синглтона - работа с базой и логгер. И первый использует второго (это очевидно, но можно и наоборот, и циклически). И расположены они в разных файлах (единицах компиляции). И вот тут легко споймать [static initialization order fiasco]https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)
- а если нужно наследоваться от какого то базового класса?

  > ну мало чего.
- private static хотя и допустимо, но выглядит откровенно наивно и не прячет нормально внутренности класса (они как бы на виду, и одновременно спрятаны).

  > почти всегда, когда в коде есть приватная статическая штука, это либо ошибка при проектировании, либо это просто нужно переместить в cpp файл

Да и к Вашему классу есть ряд вопросов. К примеру, дефолтный конструктор Вы не трогали, операторы также, а перемещения и копирования - запретили. странно это.

Comment: 1) ну можно где-нибудь вызвать статический метод init() / destroy()
2) а разве это нельзя реализовать статическими методами?
3) а синглтону нужно ли от чего-нибудь наследоваться?
4) не понял, можете разъяснить?)

ну, написал на скорую руку))